# Acidity of naphthol vs hydroxynaphthoquinone

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, resonance

I have the following two compounds whose acidity I need to compare. I tried drawing out the resonating structures but I seem to not be able to draw final conclusion.

[image: The two compounds]

I know that the conjugate base of Q has more resonance structures, but R is still more acidic according to the book, with its resonance looking like this:

[image]

Why such resonance makes it more acidic?

Comment: What even is a structure that isn't "valid", something tells me I'm better of not knowing, but not being able to tell the acidity may be your last problem... BTW You should write structures for resulting *anion*, rather then the compound itself.

Comment: @Mithoron I do know how to get at them. I just feel like that the conjugate base of Q has more resonating structures but R's conjugate base has fewer. BUT the book states R to be more acidic than Q. This is my EXACT problem

Comment: You should have started with this. That's true and R is more acidic, just like acetic acid is. Now, edit the question.

Comment: @Mithoron Is that due to Equivalent resonating structures?

Comment: Mhm, you're on right track. You got your hint, now improve the question, or it may get closed.

Comment: @Mithoron I still cant understand why R is said to have equivalent resonance structures. Could you lease explain with a diagram?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106999/discussion-between-techie5879-and-mithoron).

Answer (score 3):

For naphtol both the acidic and the basic forms have many resonance structures along the two fused benzene cycles. However, in the case of 2-hydroxy-1,4-naphthoquinone, the basic conjugated form creates novel resonance structures that engage the double bond of the quinone cycle as seen in the written resonance structure in the question. The novel resonance structures of the basic forms will stabilize the basic form. 
Therefore, the hydroxyl group in 2-hydroxy-1,4-naphthoquinone has higher tendency to lose the hydrogen ion than the hydroxyl group in naphtol. This explains the higher acidity of 2-hydroxy-1,4-naphthoquinone in comparison with naphtol.